# set url in attribute tag xml

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I´m trying to add url in tags to my xml structure. Always i´m getting this:

```
<pt:SignedInfo>
            <pt: www.w3.org TR 2001 REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
            <pt: www.w3.org 2001 04 xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
```

I need:

```
<SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
```

To try create this structure i´m doing:

```
$algorithm1 = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments";
                $algorithm2 = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
                $algorithm3 = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
                $signatureStructure = array(
                    
                    'SignedInfo' => array(
                        'CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="'.$algorithm1.'"' => "",
                        'SignatureMethod Algorithm="'.$algorithm2.'"' => "",
                        'Reference Id="main_sign" URI=""' => array(
                            'Transforms' => '',
                            'DigestMethod Algorithm="'.$algorithm3.'"' => "",
                            'DigestValue' => '',
                        )
                    ),
```

I try to pass empty array to my function that generate my xml, with this code:

```
$wrapper4 = $xml->addChild('pt:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"');
            $this->signatureStructure($signatureStructure, $xml, $wrapper4);
```

but this return a correct structure but, out of my tag:

```
<pt:Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

For example, with tag `SignedInfo` i´m doing this:

```
$wrapper4 = $xml->addChild('pt:SignedInfo');
$this->signedInfo($signedInfo, $xml, $wrapper4);
```

my return it´s:

```
<pt:Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <pt:SignatureValue/>
        <pt:KeyInfo>
            <pt:X509Data>
                <pt:X509Certificate/>
            </pt:X509Data>
        </pt:KeyInfo>
    </pt:Signature>
    **<pt:SignedInfo/>** this it´s out of signature
```

I need create this structure:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference Id="main_sign" URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>74aHiOhEsIwaRwbWLLfwQsfafGWARZJMbEu7X2nMasw=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>AARgcTwana1w....GdFBEN/3P
/FDJUHQw63h/T4ghVWs=</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIID....AyzVyw==</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
```

I´m getting:

```
<pt:Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <pt:SignedInfo>
            <pt: www.w3.org TR 2001 REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
            <pt: www.w3.org 2001 04 xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <pt:Reference Id="main_sign" URI="">
                <pt:Transforms/>
                <pt: www.w3.org 2001 04 xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <pt:DigestValue/>
            </pt:Reference>
        </pt:SignedInfo>
        <pt:SignatureValue/>
        <pt:KeyInfo>
            <pt:X509Data>
                <pt:X509Certificate/>
            </pt:X509Data>
        </pt:KeyInfo>
    </pt:Signature>
```

I´m working with `SimpleXMLElement`

UPDATE:

i find my problem. It´s simpleXMLElement delete `http://` fom my urls, if i remove `http://` set this attribute correctly. I don´t know if any way to solve this problem with this library

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML is an abstraction for basic, simple XML structures - use DOM for all features. Additionally attributes need to be set separately, not as part of the node name. The XML uses namespaces, so you should use the namespace aware methods to create element nodes.

In DOM creating and appending nodes are two separate calls. You create the node with a method of the document object, and append/insert it using the parent node object.

```php
$algorithm1 = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments";
$algorithm2 = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
$algorithm3 = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

// define a variable for the namespace URI
$XMLNS_SIGNATURE = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#';

$document = new DOMDocument();

/* append the node */
$document->appendChild(
   /* create an element node inside the namespace and store it for later use */
   $signature = $document->createElementNS($XMLNS_SIGNATURE, 'Signature')    
);

$signature->appendChild(
   $signedInfo = $document->createElementNS($XMLNS_SIGNATURE, 'SignedInfo')    
);

$signedInfo->appendChild(
   $canonicalizationMethod = $document->createElementNS($XMLNS_SIGNATURE, 'CanonicalizationMethod')
);
// set an attribute without a namespace
$canonicalizationMethod->setAttribute('Algorithm', $algorithm1);

$signedInfo->appendChild(
   $signatureMethod = $document->createElementNS($XMLNS_SIGNATURE, 'SignatureMethod')
);
$signatureMethod->setAttribute('Algorithm', $algorithm2);


$signedInfo->appendChild(
   $reference = $document->createElementNS($XMLNS_SIGNATURE, 'Reference')
);
$reference->setAttribute('Id', 'main_sign');
$reference->setAttribute('URI', '');


$reference->appendChild(
   $document->createElementNS($XMLNS_SIGNATURE, 'Transforms')
);

$reference->appendChild(
   $digestMethod = $document->createElementNS($XMLNS_SIGNATURE, 'DigestMethod')
);
$digestMethod->setAttribute('Algorithm', $algorithm3);

$reference->appendChild(
   $digestValue = $document->createElementNS($XMLNS_SIGNATURE, 'DigestValue')
);
/* set text content (replaces current content and child nodes) */
$digestValue->textContent = '123456...';

$signature
  ->appendChild(
     $document->createElementNS($XMLNS_SIGNATURE, 'SignatureValue')
  )
  ->appendChild(
     /* create a text node */
     $document->createTextNode('123456...')
  );


$document->formatOutput = true;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <Reference Id="main_sign" URI="">
      <Transforms/>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <DigestValue>123456...</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>123456...</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
```